# JavaScript program crashes page

Tags: javascript, object, math, matrix

I made a simple program in JavaScript to find **a matrix of the cofactors of a 3X3 matrix**. However, the program is crashing my page repeatedly, and I cannot find any logical error in the program. Here's my code :

```
var matrixA = {
   a11:"",
   a12:"",
   a13:"",
   a21:"",
   a22:"",
   a23:"",
   a31:"",
   a32:"",
   a33:""
};

function determinant (given,order) {
if(order==3){
    var det = (given.a11*((given.a22*given.a33)-(given.a23*given.a32)))-
    (given.a21*((given.a12*given.a33)-(given.a13*given.a32)))+
    (given.a31*((given.a12*given.a23)-(given.a13*given.a22)));
}
else if(order==2){
    var det = (given.a11*given.a22)-(given.a21*given.a12);
}
return det;
}

function cofactors(given){
var multiplier;
var temp = {
    a11:"",
    a12:"",
    a21:"",
    a22:""
};
var found_cofactor_matrix = {};
for (var i = 1; i <4; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; i < 4; j++) {
        if(((i+j)%2)==0){
            multiplier = 1;
        }
        else if(((i+j)%2)==1){
            multiplier = -1;
        }
        //Check whether row or column number is the same to make a 2X2 matrix
        for(var a = 1; a < 4; a++){
            for (var b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
                if((a==i)||(b==j)){

                } //do nothing
                else{
                    if(temp.a11==""){
                        temp.a11 = given["a"+a+b];
                    }
                    else if(temp.a12 == ""){
                        temp.a12 = given["a"+a+b];
                    }
                    else if(temp.a21 == ""){
                        temp.a21 = given["a"+a+b];
                    }
                    else if(temp.a22 == ""){
                        temp.a22 = given["a"+a+b];
                    }
                }
            };
        };
    found_cofactor_matrix["a"+i+j] = multiplier*determinant(temp,2);
    };
};
return found_cofactor_matrix;
}
```

Here, the parameter "given" is an object sent to it from the place where the function is called, and is the original matrix (matrixA) whose cofactors have to be found. I basically create a 2X2 matrix first, find its determinant and multiply it with 1 or -1 as required. I then write this value into the appropriate position in the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

`for (var j = 1; i < 4; j++) {` should be `for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {`.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. That was very silly of me. There is another problem now, the object I am logging into the console shows all property values to be NaN. What could be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you open your console? Running this code in Chrome's console yields `Uncaught ReferenceError: found_cofactor is not defined`. You are trying to define the `["a"+i+j]` property of an undefined object. It should be `found_cofactor_matrix`. 
Besides, the `determinant()` function may be undefined (it does not appear in your piece of code)

Comment: Here's my fiddle with all the required functions. https://jsfiddle.net/ag_dhruv/v9fwqpgk/

Comment: `for( var b=0` should be `for( var b=1`. Here's your updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ug1eLz7g/9/

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolons at the end of for loop. And add your determinant function.

Comment: Thank you. I have updates the jsfiddle. [Update Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qyaptds/1/)

Comment: I have update your determinant function you were not defining var det. at top of function. And your determinant function is returning NaN when calling inside cofactors function

Comment: Why is it returning NaN inside the cofactors function?

Comment: Because of loop problem! I have updated it but still can't find why your var i is not increasing.

Comment: Now it is not showing NAN but your var i is not increasing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98711/discussion-between-ag-dhruv-and-ahmed-khan).

Comment: Which one should I check? Can't find the latest edited one.